# Did people not wear seat belts in 1970s?

Tags: realism, once-upon-a-time-in-hollywood

In the movie *Once Upon a Time in Hollywood*, the characters played by Leonardo Di Caprio and Brad Pitt never wear seat belts.

I do not think characters such as Planski and Sharon wear seat belts either.

Is it realistic for U.S. citizens living during that era?

Comment: Some people still don't wear seatbelts in 2020.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Once Upon a Time in Hollywood* takes place in 1969, at which time seat belts were not mandatory to wear and were thus not widely used. As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seat_belt#Homologation_and_testing):

> Starting in 1971 and ending in 1972, the United States conducted a research project on seat belt effectiveness on a total of 40,000 vehicle occupants using car accident reports collected during that time. Of these 40,000 occupants, 18% were reported wearing lap belts, or two-point safety belts, 2% were reported wearing a three-point safety belt, and the remaining 80% were reported as wearing no safety belt.

Comment: I remember being driven by my father who didn't wear a seatbelt until it became law in 1983 - in the UK.  This confirms it was no different in the USA.

Comment: Batman wore a seatbelt in the 60’s, but he’s an exception.

Answer (score 6):

Just as a data point, per [the Dec 1, 1984 issue of the New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/1984/12/01/nyregion/state-seat-belt-law-takes-effect-today.html):

> ## State Seat Belt Law Takes Effect Today
>
> Dec. 1, 1984
>
> New York State's mandatory seat belt law - the first in the nation - went into effect today.
>
> Drivers and front-seat passengers must wear seat belts or face fines of up to $50.
>
> Drivers will be liable for any passengers under 16 who are not strapped in the front seat. Front-seat passengers over 16 will be personally liable for the penalties.
>
> There will be a one-month grace period, until Jan. 1, before penalties are imposed.
>
> Under an earlier law, children under 10 must be secured by a safety belt or a safety seat in either the front or back seats.
>
> Taxicabs, school buses, emergency vehicles and commercial vans and trucks are exempt from the new law. Physicians can provide waivers to motorists or passengers who cannot wear seat belts for medical reasons. The automobile industry is selling adaptors for people too large or too small to be secured by a safety belt.

Answer (score 0):

In the United States which vehicles had to have seat belts built into the vehicle and what type also varied by year.

So wearing a seat beat, or even having them available in the vehicle, depends on the type of vehicle and the year.  A car might require seat belts in a particular year, while a same year truck might not have them.

Even which seats had to have belts or which types of belts varied by year.  For example, the back seat, or second row seats, might have different requirements from the front seats in the same year and vehicle type.